# C# Threadstart Error

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to start a new thread for one simple method but that method has variables I need to pass it.

```
    Thread tempmovethread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(widget.moveXYZINCHES(xval,yval,zval));
```

I am getting the error: "Method name expected".

That is the right method name and I did something very similar to this in an earlier bit of code and it worked, the only difference is the method I called before didnt need any variables to be passed:

```
    executethread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(execute.RunRecipe));
```

Is it possible to start a new thread and pass the variables like this, or do I have to do it another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an Action to create the correct delegate type.

```
Thread tempmovethreading = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Action(() => widget.moveXYZINCHES(xval,yval,zval)));
```

Comment: Like it, beautiful! +1 But will be warning about "access to modified closure"?

Answer (score 3):

tempmovethread = new Thread(new ParametrizedThreadStart(widget.moveXYZINCHES);
tempmovethread.Start(new []{xval,yval,zval});

**BUT**

you should appropriately change the method's signature like this (assuming the used parameters are of type int:

```
public void moveXYZINCHES(object state)
{
  int xval = (state as int[])[0],yval = (state as int[])[1],zval = (state as int[])[2];
  ...your code
}
```

Comment: Alright, I understand the first part, but after your "but" statement, i get a little lost... im not too familiar with the state as commands in C#, why do I need to do this?

Comment: because the ParametrizedThreadStart accepts only function with specific set of parameters - only f(object state), for this you have to wrap your parameters into the single object to pass them into thread's function. But I really like the @Bob Vale's answer with Action using